# Calculate avg in group for a field which represents array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
"name":"St Peterburg",
"checkInAt" : ISODate(...),
"areas": [
        {"length":2.0; "width":3.0}, 
        {"length":4.0; "width":3.0}, 
        {"length":2.0; "width":1.0}
       ]

}
```

I need a query which would group these documents by day and for each group calculate a single decimal which is equal to average of all (length * width) among all areas arrays in the group. So, if in a group I have two documents:

```
A { areas:[{"length":2; "width":3}; {"length":3; "width":4};], 
B { areas:[{"length":4; "width":5}; {"length":5; "width":6};]
```

I would need to calculate `X = avg(2*3;3*4;4*5;5*6)`;

So far my query looks like:

```
db.getCollection('areas').aggregate([
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {
                    "$dateToString": {
                        "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                        "date": "$checkInAt"
                    }
                },

                "avgArea": {$avg: {"$multiply":["$$areas.length","$$areas.width"]}}
            }
        }
    ])
```

But this doesn't work,

Would be really grateful for the hints of how can I make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
db.getCollection('areas').aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$areas" // flatten the "areas" array into multiple documents
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$checkInAt", // group everything by "checkInAt"
        "avgArea": { $avg: { $multiply: [ "$areas.length", "$areas.width" ] } } // calculate the average
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Is that possible to do it without projection? To tell the truth, my first solution looked exactly as yours. However, this solution had been declined by one of my colleagues with a link to mongo documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation.

```
db.getCollection('areas').aggregate(
[{"$unwind":"$areas"},
 {"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m-%d","date":"$checkInAt"}
  },
  "avgArea":{
    "$avg":{"$multiply":["$areas.length","$areas.width"]}
  }
}}])
```

You can also calculate averages without `$unwind`. Calculate the `$sum` across all the arrays, first by calculating the `$sum` for each array followed by all arrays for each group.

Keep the count of arrays in a separate field.

`$project` avg by dividing sum with count.

```
db.getCollection('areas').aggregate(
[{"$group":{
  "_id":{
      "$dateToString":{"format":"%Y-%m-%d","date":"$checkInAt"}
   },
  "sumArea":{
    "$sum":{
      "$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":"$areas",
          "as":"val",
          "in":{"$multiply":["$$val.length","$$val.width"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "countArea":{"$sum":{"$size":"$areas"}}
}},
{"$project":{
  "avgArea":{"$divide":["$sumArea","$countArea"]}
}}])
```

Comment: I'm getting confused but this might also be ok without the final $project stage? `db.getCollection('test').aggregate([{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date":"$checkInAt"
            }
        },
        "avgArea": {
        "$avg": {
            "$avg": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$areas",
                    "as": "val",
                    "in": { "$multiply": [ "$$val.length", "$$val.width" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}])`

Comment: No, you are right. That is what I was aiming for but couldn't make sense in terms of how the operators will be evaluated.  I'll play little bit more with this. Thank you for comment. Updated.

Comment: @dnickless Alright it turns out what I thought initial is correct. This can be best realized with array of different sizes. For ex, take two arrays. [1] & [1,2]. expected output is 1.33 but your query will output 1.25 ( ( 1/1 + 3/2 ) / 2 ). So you have to use $project stage to manually calculate avg.

Comment: That makes sense. I was also experimenting with a $reduce based version last night and stumbled across the same problem.